# Javascript if no value else

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I'm using a code from codrops to create a thumbnail grid with an expanding view. Now everything is working fine but instead of only images i inserted a video player too ( youtube and vimeo ) now my problem is if the data attribute has no value it shouldn't display the player. And i can't seem to get the if else statement to work :S ( sorry beginner ). Thanks in advance

Tutorial here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

HTML here:
http://pastebin.com/G6cwikNZ

Javascript here:
http://pastebin.com/uVedxC91

EDIT:
The tags used in the javascript are the $vm and the $yt, and i checked the console log and they aren't defined anywhere but if i typ in random stuff in the data-vm or data-yt they do give me that ouput.. weird stuff..

Comment: Bring your JavaScript, html and CSS into your question.

Comment: @DavidThomas but only relevant portions, his code is **HUGE**

Comment: http://pastebin.com/dchtZ1Y0 i guess this the main Javascript part for displaying stuff from html5 data-attributes where s.vm is the value given in the html.

Comment: do you know how to paste in code on here?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (typeof data === "undefined"){
    ///Do things
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!data ){
   // data is undefined. 
}
```

Comment: This would work in this case, but only because his `data` will never be set to a boolean, but in other cases this will return true if his `data` variable is simply set to `false`

Comment: @pandavenger also if data is 0